# dynamic programming practice algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to find a recurrence relation and algorithm to the following problem but have been stuck for a few days:

There are a total of *H* > *n* hours in which to work on the *n* school projects (all of which are due at exactly the same time) and you want to decide now to divide up this time. For simplicity, assume that *H* is a positive integer, and that you will spend an integer number of hours on each project. You have come up with a set of functions *f*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *f<sub>n</sub>* (a rough estimate, of course) such that working *x* hours on project i will get you a grade of *f<sub>i</sub>*(*x*) on that project.

May assume that *f<sub>i</sub>*(*x*) does not decrease if *x* increases and each project will be graded on a scale from 1 to 100.

So, given *H* and *f*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *f<sub>n</sub>*, you need to determine how many (integer) hours you will spend on each project so your average grade is as large as possible (max grade).

- Finding recurrence relation for *G*[*H*, *j*], where *G*[*H*, *j*] is the sum of the grades obtained by spending *H* hours in total on the projects for courses 1, 2, ... *j*
- Finding a dynamic programming algorithm that computes *G*[*H*, *n*]

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: This is just the [unbounded knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem) in disguise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
G[H<0, j] = -Infinity
G[H, 0] = 0
G[H, j] = max(G[H-i, j-1]+f_j(i)) for 0<=i<=H
```

In the recurrence I'm trying to find the best number of hours to work on the project j. This solution is O(H^2*n).